# When was not being able to release Pokemon with HM moves implemented?

Tags: pokemon-series

As TwitchPlaysPokemon taught us, it is possible in early generations to release pokemon with critical HM moves, making it possible to permanently 'lose' the game.

However, at a certain point in the series, you could no longer release such a pokemon, presumably to avoid getting 'stuck' in this manner.

When in the series was this rule of not being able to release an HM-knowing pokemon implemented?

Comment: Well, this explains why I couldn't overwrite 'Strength' with a better move, and instead had to get rid of a move I wanted to keep.  Which is pretty stupid, since it would have allowed me to remove 'Strength' if I had leveled up in a different location :(

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: The inability to *delete* an HM move has been there from the start, but they added the Move Deleter in GSC to bypass that lock. The question, however, is about *releasing a Pokémon* with an HM move.

Comment: Could you provide an example of "losing" the game by releasing a Pokémon that knows a required HM move? As far as I know, all HMs can be used ad infinitum.

Comment: @Nolonar: If you're on Cinnabar Island and release all of your Pokémon that know *or can learn* Surf (including Kabuto/Omanyte), and you never got the Fly HM or any of the fishing rods, your only way out is to trade over a Surfing Pokémon from another game.

Comment: @jwodder, kind of trivial, but don't forget to heal at the Cinnabar pokemon center so you can't whiteout/teleport/dig/escaperope out. Also, discarding all sellable items, balls, and money is an alternative to avoiding fishing rods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature was implemented in Gen 3 (**NOT** Gen 2). In fact, you can find videos online of people getting stuck in Cianwood by releasing all their Surf-capable pokemon, much like Cinnabar in gen 1. I have also personally tested this on a real Game Boy.

Note that due to an oversight, it is possible to get stuck in D/P/Pt by trading away your Finneon to Meister if it's your only pokemon that knows Surf. You still can't release them though.